# Swift optimization level breaks converting NSArray to Array

Tags: swift, nsarray

The following (somewhat contrived) code works when *Swift Optimization Level* is set to *None [-Onone]* (default for debug):

```
    let nsa = NSArray(array: ["foo", "bar"])
    let a = nsa as [String]
```

But the app crashes ([crash log](http://pastebin.com/fdn20buk)) during run-time when set to *Fastest [-O]* (default for release).

I luckily discovered I can work around the issue by doing this:

```
    let a = nsa as [AnyObject] as [String]
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Could you help me understand why this is happening?
2. Is there a better way to convert an NSArray to an Array?

### UPDATE

This does seem to be a bug. I have not reported it to Apple. If someone else would like to take the time to do so, please do!

Comment: Side note: similar situation for converting NSMutableArray to Array: http://dev.eltima.com/post/96538497489/convert-nsmutablearray-to-swift-array

Comment: What do you mean "breaks"?  What messages are produced?

Comment: @HotLicks the app crashes when it gets to that code. Ummm... let me find out... please hold...

Comment: @HotLicks Ok, I added a link to the crash log.

Comment: That's a disassembly.  No call stack?  No error message?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'd report it to Apple and move on.

Comment: @HotLicks That's all I get. No error message. It builds and runs fine without swift optimization. It builds fine even with swift optimization, it just breaks when it gets to that code. For testing purporses, I'm running that in applicationDidFinishLaunching before anything else.

Comment: BTW the example _is_ contrived because in real life you will get an NSArray from Cocoa as an `[AnyObject]` so the problem won't arise.

Comment: @matt You're right. The way that I ran this was reusing code from an ObjectiveC app where a class had a NSMutableArray property. I've come to learn there's a better way to convert an NSMutableArray to Array (see my first comment), but before I found that, my thought process led me to NSMutableArray -> NSArray -> Array.

Comment: @tybro0103 It's still a good bug! Please do report it and let Apple deal with it.

Comment: @tybro0103 BTW I just tested this for the analogous NSDictionary <-> Dictionary situation and I get the same crash and the same workaround; you have to cast explicitly to `[NSObject:AnyObject]` as an intermediary. This bug is looking better and better! The problem is that you _are_ likely to pass a dictionary into Cocoa and out again, because Swift's Dictionary has no instance methods so you'll want Cocoa to do the work for you.

Comment: This is a very serious bug with the Swift optimization mechanism, which has caused my app to crash in production, (and we didn't catch it before because it would only crash if the array being converted had at least one item). Updating to the latest Xcode did not solve the issue. The workaround mentioned here works great until Apple addresses this.

Comment: Still an issue with todays release of Xcode 6.2. Thanks a ton for the workaround you have found. In our case I found it would interestingly work when we add `NSLog("%@", nsa)`  (to stay with your example) right behind the declaration. But as soon as that line was removed it crashed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003323/memory-access-crash-only-in-archived-cocoa-application-exc-bad-access-exc-i386

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be fixed on Xcode `Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)`.

And, not an answer to your original problem but as the new Swift 1.2 introduced, `as` is a forced cast, now replaced by more explicit `as!`. You should expect an `NSArray` to `Array<T>` where `T != AnyObject or NSObject` to crash.

You'd better use conditional cast `as?`. Avoid `!` any time it's possible.

```
let nsa = NSArray(array: ["foo", "bar"])
if let a = nsa as? [String] {
    println("a \(a)")
}
```